# how to remove last three lines in text document list and append first line from this three

Tags: python-3.x

can you help me figure out with this problem

if I have text document with list line by line

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
```

how to remove last 3 lines in the text document, just make minus three lines last from all exist lines, provided that the list is constantly updated with new lines

and also remember first line word from deleted three, not sure maybe with append

```
word1
word2 <--- must be removed but remember for further manipulation 
word3 <--- must be removed
word4 <--- must be removed
```

and then I want back word2 which was remembered to my text document this way:

```
word1
word2 <--- back it to the list where it was before with two symbols 
new word <--- new word comes here and second two lines space and X 

X
```

but I'm not really sure how to find last three lines and fix first from it

Answer (score 0):

Tackling your first issue, finding the last 3 lines of your list, you can use [-3:]

In code it might look something like this:

```
list1 = []
list1.append('The first text item')
list1.append('Now the second text item')
list1.append('This one is the third text item')
list1.append('Finally the fourth text item')

list2 = list1[-3:]
```

You can also delete the last 3 items from the first list with

```
del list1[-3:]
```

If you use the above and put the last 3 text items into a separate list, obtaining the first word from each is straight forward.

So, read in the text document to a list, adjust the list and output the new list to a temp file.

Delete the original text document and rename the temp file.

Comment: but how to remove line inside text document, all my results now is string `Extend list:  [['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '6\n'], '6', '\n\n', 'X']`

Comment: The easy way to remove in a text document is to read in the lines from the text document to a list. Remove the last 3 lines from the list. Write that to a new temporary text document (eg. Temp.txt). Then delete the first text document and then rename the temp file to the original name.